# Python code to find the transpose of a matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix

I have the following code to find the transpose of a matrix

```
n,m=map(int,raw_input().split())
a=[]
for i in range(n):
    a.append(map(int,raw_input().split()))
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        a[i][j],a[j][i]=a[j][i],a[i][j]
for i in a:         #printing transpose
    print i
```

But when i print the resultant transpose matrix, source matrix elements is getting printed....Is there any problem with the code or logic??

Comment: Have you printed the matrix prior to transposing it?

Comment: how does the result of `raw_input()` look like?

Comment: Hint: say your matrix is 3x3.  When `i,j == 1,2`, you swap `a[1][2]` with `a[2][1]`.  What will happen when `i,j == 2,1`?

Answer (score 4):

Using numpy,

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
a.transpose()
```

Comment: Numpy arrays also have a `T` property that is a *view* to the transpose matrix. Using the view you don't even need to compute the transpose so it would be constant time

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative answer i suggest use `zip` function for find transposition of a matrix :

```
>>> a=[[1,2,3],[0,7,8],[12,40,9]]
>>> map(list,zip(*a))
[[1, 0, 12], [2, 7, 40], [3, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix transpose is reflexive i.e.

i , j = x, y and swap a[i] with a[j] then for i, j = y, x it will swap a[i] and a[j] and it would restore the values

So you need to enforce an ordering

```
def foo():
    n,m=map(int,raw_input().split())
    a=[]
    for i in range(n):
        a.append(map(int,raw_input().split()))
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(i+1, n): # ensure j > i
            a[i][j],a[j][i]=a[j][i],a[i][j]
    for i in a:         #printing transpose
        print i
```

**Note**, Python libraries already has a function that performs transpose of a 2 dimensional lists called `zip`

```
def foo():
    n,m=map(int,raw_input().split())
    a=[]
    for i in range(n):
        a.append(map(int,raw_input().split()))
    zip(*a)
    for i in a:         #printing transpose
        print i
```